# VBA Macro to not Copy Cell over to Another Sheet if Value Already Exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of about 5000 contacts with their information organized by the work they perform.  Some are listed multiple times if they perform several types of work.  I use the list to send notifications to the contacts if they've been selected in accordance with the work they perform.

I use the Email Merge function to send individual emails and so I wrote a macro to copy the contact's email over to another worksheet if they've been selected.

```
Sub CopySelectedMasterToMerge()

Dim RangeToConsider2 As Range
Dim strAddresses2 As String
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet

Set shtSrc = Sheets("MASTER")       'source sheet
Set shtDest = Sheets("Email Merge")  'destination sheet
destRow = 2                         'start copying to this row
Set RangeToConsider2 = Range("K4:K7000")

For Each Cell In RangeToConsider2
If Cell.Value = "a" Then
    If Cell.Offset(0, 1) <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 6).Cells.Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
    destRow = destRow + 1
    End If
End If
Next Cell
Worksheets("Email Merge").Activate
End Sub
```

This, along with the Email Merge, work really well except the contacts with multiple listings are receiving additional copies of the same email.

How can I prevent an email being copied over again if it already exists on the other Worksheet?

**Update** - using @BigBen's suggestion, I got the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to work.

```
For Each Cell In RangeToConsider2

    If Cell.Value = "a" Then
        EmailAddress = Cell.Offset(0, 6)
        If Cell.Offset(0, 1) <> "ZZZZZZZZZ" Then
            CountCheck = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SearchArea, EmailAddress)
            If CountCheck < 1 Then
                 Cell.Offset(0, 6).Cells.Copy shtDest.Cells(destRow, 1)
            destRow = destRow + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: Possibly using `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`, or `Application.Match`, or `Range.Find`.

Comment: Just a general comment unrelated to your question - it is good practise when using Range to confine it to the sheet the range is on, otherwise you can get unexpected results if the active sheet changes. In this case it would be Set RangeToConsider2 = shtSrc.Range("K4:K7000").

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Yes, that is a really good idea that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Thank you @BigBen !  I was able to get it to work using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are copying email addresses from one sheet to another based on criteria and you want the resulting list to be unique?

You could use an intermediate structure like a Collection or a Dictionary to test for uniqueness.

A Dictionary is a key-value structure where the keys must be unique. The value can be the same as the key. I prefer to use a Dictionary because it has a built in function to test for the existence of a key. If you used a Collection you would have to write your own :)

Basically as you run through the list of emails you test for their existence in the Dictionary and only add new entries. You then use the Dictionary contents to decide who to mail to - you don't even need to copy them to a new sheet. Of course you still can if you need them for some other purpose.

Here is an excellent [tutorial](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) on what they are and how to use them.

Comment: Yes in your first paragraph.  I'm not familiar with Dictionary so thank you for the tutorial and suggestion.  I'll give it a read and see if I can figure it out / see if it works.  As much as I understand it, Email Merge with Microsoft requires a separate list on a separate worksheet in order to work correctly.  It's at least how I've been using it.  It's also good to be able to record, search and review quickly who was included in the list.

Comment: I don't think this will work because of memory limitations.  There's a good change the Dictionary would need to store 5000+ entries in order to work.  For other functions, I've found my PCs limit to be around 1000 and I also run memory heavy other programs at the same time.